# Abbreviate Troy McClure's surname in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

Imagine [Troy McClure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_McClure) wrote a book and his surname funnily enough now appears *abbreviated* in a biblatex+biber bibliography. The output of this is "M., Troy", but imho should better be "McC., Troy".

### Question

How can I make biblatex detect prefixes like this (or at least this particular one) and get the correct abbreviated surname?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{mcd,
    author={McClure, Troy},
    title={Abbreviating My Surname In Biblatex Doesn't Work Well}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#2}{#3}{#5}{#7}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Should be "**McC.**, Troy. (…)".

PS: For biblatex 3.3 the \DeclareNameFormat command should be (untested):

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamilyi}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartpre‌​fix}{\namepartsuffix}}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: On the line `\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#2}{#3}{#5}{#7}}`, I get an "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\blx@defformat@d.`" message.

Comment: i'm not a biblatex user, but in bibtex, i would expect that `{McC}lure` would do what you want.

Comment: @Mico Do you use biblatex 3.3? I add the correct line for this version in the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried that, but it doesn't change anything at least with biblatex 1.7. Does this really work with bibtex?

Comment: @dessert - I indeed have biblatex 3.3 on my system. With your updated code, I get an error mesage about `\namepartpre‌​fix` not being defined.

Comment: I'd be very surprised to get, from `McClure, Troy` the author's name printed as “M. Troy”, but rather “T. McClure”. Please, explain.

Comment: @egreg I use a bibliography style where author surnames in fact appear two times per entry: One time just the surname, the other time all names with the surname abbreviated. Something like "Troy 2016: McC., Troy. …"

Comment: Removing the `{\namepartpre‌​fix}` substring lets me compile your code. However, I get "Troy M.", not "M., Troy", i.e., what's shown in your screenshot.

Comment: It makes no sense, in my opinion. Since when authors are identified by given name?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - You were close: what's needed is `{\relax McC}lure`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for testing, they really changed this a lot with biblatex 3.3! -.- `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` may help. Regardless of the name order the issue remains the same.

Comment: @egreg I meant to write "McClure 2016: McC., Troy. …" – sorry about that!

Comment: It makes no sense either. Before the colon you have the identifier used in the document, after it the *essential* data for specifying the reference.

Comment: @egreg Why not? This way the bib entries give the full (!) citation, which is as in authoryear, and after that the full bibliography entry. Yes indeed, the author's last name and the year are repeated once in this style, but on the other hand it gives the full citation key in front of the entry.

Comment: I have to agree that this seems like a really bad idea.... Bibliographies should present information clearly so that others can figure out  (easily!) who and what the work is. Abbreviating names in this way is liable to confuse many readers more than is desirable.

Comment: @jon I think I've been misunderstood: The author's surname actually appears two times per entry in my style, and in only one of these it's abbreviated. The in-text citation is "McClure 2016" and in the bib this is specified with e.g. "McClure 2016: McC., Troy. Title. Publisher Location. 2016". The advantage of tis style in comparison to the authoryear standard behavior is that the identifier "McClure 2016" appears *completely* in the bib instead of having it dissolved to "McClure, Troy (2016). Title. …", which I consider bad style.

Comment: I think I do understand, though we'll have to agree to disagree on what constitutes bad style.  But I can't help wondering: What happens when it's a two- or three-author work?

Comment: @jon In fact it's not even my own style, but the style of my field of work, of course. When there's a work of multiple authors, every surname that appeared written out in the identifier is abbreviated in the bib entry, e.g. "McClure/McDonald 2016: McC., Troy and McD., Ron. …" Even if the abbreviated form of the author's surname happened to be identical this still is clear, as the names appear in the same order as in the identifier, e.g. "McClure/McConald 2016: McC., Troy and McC., Ronald. …". However, abbreviated surnames are definitely *not* well implemented in biblatex.

Comment: Well, you must agree it is an unusual style in the sense that it is not particularly common.   And it does not seem well thought out if it cares about abbreviating McClure to McC. (which serves no practical purpose) but does not worry about two separate authors with the same forename and the same first letter(s) of the last appearing in the same list --- e.g., 'Jonathan Barnes' and 'Jonathan Barber' or 'David Smith' and 'David Smythe'. (Or is 'McC.' an attempt to deal with many M-names?)  ... However, as an academic TeX problem, I'm happy to see an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the author field to

```
author={{\relax McC}lure, Troy},
```

lets you achieve your objective, *viz.*, make the surname show up as `McC`.

The full MWE (used with biblatex v. 3.3) -- note that I had to remove `{\namepartpre‌​fix}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{mcd,
    author={{\relax McC}lure, Troy},
    title={Abbreviating My Surname \dots},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\nameparts{#1}%
   \usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamilyi}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartsuffix}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Under certain circumstances this produces an unwanted extra space before the last name, this can be resolved using `{\relax{}McC}lure`.

Comment: @dessert - Please be a bit more specific as to what the "certain circumstances" may entail. TeX should be eating up the space after `\relax`. If that's not the case, something odd may be going on.

Comment: Sorry about that. The identifier used in the document in authoryear style is rendered as " McClure 2016" with the space. You can check that using this style and citing the book with e.g. \parencite{mcd}.

Comment: @dessert - Many thanks for providing this specific example.

Comment: Nevertheless I accept your answer, as \relax is the right thing to do. Thanks again for your patience, especially with the \DeclareNameFormat struggle!